# How to save multiple items from JSON post in database using Yii

Tags: php, json, yii

What I'm trying to achieve here is to save multiple items from JSON post data into database whenever there's a new registration.

I've successfully save a single registration. But if I have multiple registrations, it won't save all data passed. It will save only the first item.

Here's the JSON post data captured:

```
{"id" : "1514358676612-F9RM4",
  "accountId" : 128768,
  "eventId" : 206218,
  "timestamp" : 1514358676612,
  "url" : "http://hub.mymagic.my/bizzabo/bizzaboCallback",
  "details" : {
    "items" : [ {
      "contactEmail" : "ikram@mymagic.my",
      "created" : "2017-12-27T07:09:21.000+0000",
      "ticketPaid" : 0,
      "contactFirstName" : "Ikram",
      "contactLastName" : "Khasim",
      "currency" : "USD",
      "validity" : "valid",
      "status" : "completed",
      "ticketType" : "test",
      "ticketId" : 1296403,
      "invoice" : false,
      "contactName" : "Ikram Khasim",
      "paymentStatus" : "completed",
      "registrationForm" : {
        "type_of_person" : "Experienced Entrepreneur",
        "firstName" : "Ikram",
        "organisation__instit" : "MaGIC",
        "lastName" : "Khasim",
        "gender" : "Male | Lelaki",
        "age_group" : "22-24",
        "mobileNumber" : "0193533005",
        "email" : "ikram@mymagic.my",
        "how_did_you_hear_abo" : "Word of mouth"
      },
      "type" : "ticket"
    }, {
      "contactEmail" : "yasmin@mymagic.my",
      "created" : "2017-12-27T07:09:21.000+0000",
      "ticketPaid" : 0,
      "contactFirstName" : "Ikram",
      "contactLastName" : "Khasim",
      "currency" : "USD",
      "validity" : "valid",
      "status" : "completed",
      "ticketType" : "test",
      "ticketId" : 1296404,
      "invoice" : false,
      "contactName" : "Ikram Khasim",
      "paymentStatus" : "completed",
      "registrationForm" : {
        "type_of_person" : "Experienced Entrepreneur",
        "firstName" : "Ikram",
        "organisation__instit" : "MaGIC",
        "lastName" : "Khasim",
        "gender" : "Male | Lelaki",
        "age_group" : "22-24",
        "mobileNumber" : "0193533005",
        "email" : "yasmin@mymagic.my",
        "how_did_you_hear_abo" : "Word of mouth"
      },
      "type" : "ticket"
    } ],
    "contactEmail" : "ikram@mymagic.my",
    "contactFirstName" : "Ikram",
    "contactLastName" : "Khasim",
    "currency" : "USD",
    "action" : "charge",
    "status" : "completed",
    "quantity" : 2,
    "invoice" : false,
    "contactName" : "Ikram Khasim",
    "paymentStatus" : "completed",
    "amount" : 0,
    "orderId" : 651560
  },
  "type" : "orderCreated"
}
```

And this is the code to save the JSON post data items into database. It successfully stored the first item into the database, however didn't save the second item.

```
public function actionBizzaboCallback()
{
    $junk = new Junk;
    $junk->code = 'bizzabo-bizzaboCallback-'.time();

    $junk->content .= serialize($_POST);

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        // fetch RAW input
        $json = file_get_contents('php://input');

        // expecting valid json
        if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
            $junk = new Junk;
            $junk->code = 'bizzabo-getJSONError-'.time();
            $junk->content = sprintf('JSON not captured at : %s', Yii::app()->params['masterDomain']);
            die(header('HTTP/1.0 415 Unsupported Media Type'));
        } else {
            // check if registration exist
                // decode json
                $objects = json_decode($json);

                //create new registration
                $object = new EventRegistration;
                $object->event_code = $objects->eventId;

                $tmps = HUB::getEventCode($object->event_code);
                $object->event_id = $tmps->id;

                $object->event_vendor_code = 'bizzabo'; 
                $object->registration_code = $objects->details->items[0]->ticketId;
                $object->full_name = sprintf('%s %s', $objects->details->items[0]->registrationForm->firstName, $objects->details->items[0]->registrationForm->lastName);
                $object->first_name = $objects->details->items[0]->registrationForm->firstName;
                $object->last_name = $objects->details->items[0]->registrationForm->lastName;
                $object->email = $objects->details->items[0]->registrationForm->email;

                $object->date_registered = time();
                $object->date_payment = time();
                $object->json_original = json_decode($json,true);
                $object->date_added = time();
                $object->date_modified = time();

                if($object->save()){
                    $success = 'successfully insert data into db';
                }else{
                    $fail = $object->errors;
                    $status = 'failed insert data into db';
                }
                //create junk
                $junk = new Junk;
                $junk->code = 'bizzabo-getBizzaboRegistrationIntoDB-'.time();
                $junk->content = sprintf('Success(%s) or Fail(%s) with error message (%s). With first name is %s and last name is %s. JSON Captured: %s', $success, $status, $fail, $object->first_name, $object->last_name, $json);
        }
    }
    $junk->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should iterate over the items content for save the related  values eg:

```
 } else {
        // check if registration exist
            // decode json
            $objects = json_decode($json);
            foreach( $object->details->items as $key = $value){
            //create new registration
            $object = new EventRegistration;
            $object->event_code = $objects->eventId;

            $tmps = HUB::getEventCode($object->event_code);
            $object->event_id = $tmps->id;

            $object->event_vendor_code = 'bizzabo'; 

            // apply the actual item value 
            $object->registration_code = $value->ticketId;
            $object->full_name = sprintf('%s %s', 
                        $value->registrationForm->firstName, 
                        $value->registrationForm->lastName);
            .......
            ......

            }
```